# Compressing an Outlook PST programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, pst

[This Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3785816/Compact-PST-File-in-Outlook.aspx) is the only resource I can find that says the API for compressing a PST file is not exposed.  Can anyone verify this or provide information otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the link you posted is correct.  There is no API for compacting the PST.

Depending on how many items in the PST you have, one option may be to create a new PST and move the items over, then delete the old PST.  Granted, that's not an elegant solution by any means, but it's an option.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe.  I couldn't find any other corroborating evidence that said yes or no besides that one link.